Positive definiteness of a diagonal matrix and boundedness of specific set
Problem: Let $D\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a diagonal matrix. Show that the set $$E=\{x\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1} \mid x^tDx\leq 1 \}$$ is bounded if and only if the diagonal entries of $D$ are positive.
Here we say that $E$ is bounded if $\lVert x\rVert \leq M$ for every $x\in E$ and some $0<M<\infty$.
So far: For the ''$\Leftarrow$'' direction, since the entries $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ of $D$ (i.e. its eigenvalues) are positive, it is positive definite, so $x^tDx>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$. Then if $x=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}\in E\subset \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$ we have $$0<x^tDx=\lambda_1x_1^2 +\ldots + \lambda_nx_n^2\leq 1.$$ Now it's clear that the norm of $x$ has to be bounded, but I'm not sure how to show this formally.
For the ''$\Rightarrow$'' direction I don't see a good way to start.

Sure, but that's why we require the entries of $D$ to be positive, not just non-negative.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Assume $E$ is bounded. If there exists a nonpositive entry of the diagonal of $D$, say $d_k \le 0$, set
$$
    x_n = (0, 0, \ldots, 0, n, 0, \ldots, 0)
$$
where the number $n$ is at the $k$-entry. Then,
$$
   x_n^T D x_n = d_k n^2 \le 0 \le 1
$$
Thus, $x_n \in E \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. But $\lVert x_n \rVert = n \rightarrow \infty$, which is a contradiction.
$(\Leftarrow)$ Assume that all of the diagonal entries of $D$ are postive, $d_k > 0$. Then, like the way you do in your post, if $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in E$, we have
$$
    d_k x_k^2 \le \sum_{i = 1}^n d_i x_i^2 \le 1
$$
i.e,
$$
    x_k^2 \le \dfrac{1}{d_k}
$$
which implies
$$
   \lVert x \rVert \le \sqrt{\sum_{k = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{d_k}} < \infty, \ \forall x \in E
$$
